# Manually initialize ActiveRecord object with custom select values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Goal: I want to initialize a record like ActiveRecord does under the hood.

Secondary goal: I also want to understand ActiveRecord better.

Why: I want an ActiveRecord object with values that I selected myself using hard-written SQL.

Analogy: I can do

```
Foo.first
```

and that will give me a regular `Foo` instance with all of its columns `Foo<id: 1, name: "ABC">`

I can also do

```
Foo.select('1 AS bar').first
```

and I'll get an instance of `Foo` that I can then call `foo.bar` and it will return 1, EVEN if the `Foo` table doesn't have a 'bar' column. Nice!

Background: I have a hash of properties, `{bar 1, id: 1, name: "ABC"}`. I want to initialize an instance of `Foo` that will have a `bar` property even though the Foo `table` doesn't have a `bar` column.

Error: If I try to initialize `Foo` with those properties, I'll get the error `ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'bar' for Foo`

Condition: I don't want to have an `attribute :bar` in the `Foo` class, nor do I want an `attr_accessor :bar` either.

Reasoning: I know that ActiveRecord is doing something under the hood when I `select` columns that it doesn't have so that in the end I get an object with those properties. What is it doing?

Comment: Not a full answer so I will leave this here as a comment but "attributes" in an ActiveRecord object are actually just a `Hash` look up. These keys (attributes) are simply stored in the `@attributes` `Hash` and when you call an "attribute" method it simply fetches from this instance variable [#_read_attribute](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb#L35)

Comment: I did not run through the entire code so I don't guarantee correctness but the select version is likely handled through functionality like https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f855139f3d2bb9b032613279d0adfbd6a77a2d07/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L423 and https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f7e19dee026a6cec4d50c28f84da88b0f1397c40/activerecord/lib/active_record/core.rb#L602 because this just accepts the attributes as is and `init_internals` calls `define_attribute_methods`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have an active-record model `Foo`:

```rb
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
end
```

You may instantiate a new instance of that model with arbitrary attribute values without fetching them through SQL using the [`ActiveRecord::Persistence.instantiate`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2f5136a/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L346) method:

```rb
attributes = {
  "id" => 1,
  "foo" => 1,
  "name" => "ABC"
}

foo = Foo.instantiate(attributes)
# => #<Foo:0x00007fcae44fee88 id: 1>
```

#### Attributes Hash requires Strings

Please note that the `attributes` hash is required provide the keys as `String`, not as `Symbol`. So, you need to have `attributes = {"id" => 1, "foo" => 1, "name" => "ABC"}` rather than `attributes = {id: 1, foo: 1, name: "ABC"}`.

If you already have a hash with `Symbol` keys, you may convert it using `Hash#stringify_keys`:

```rb
attributes = {id: 1, foo: 1, name: "ABC"}
attributes.stringify_keys  # => {"id" => 1, "foo" => 1, "name" => "ABC"}

foo = Foo.instantiate(attributes.stringify_keys)
```

#### Retrieve Attributes

From the instance `foo`, you may retrieve the attributes like this:

```rb
foo.attributes
# => {"id"=>1, "bar"=>1, "name"=>"ABC"}

# or:
foo.bar
# => 1
```

### Further Resources

- [`ActiveRecord::Persistence.instantiate`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2f5136a/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L346)
- Old, but interesting and very well-done railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/239-activerecord-relation-walkthrough